# No me borra los datos de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una prueba en la cual necesito eliminar los datos de una base de datos, borrando solamente la fila que imprimo en una tabla.
En principio el codigo esta correcto pero no se ejecuta el borrado.
Supongo que estare pasando por alto algun error.

HTML

```html
<?php
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "nba");
    $sql ="SELECT nombre, ciudad, conferencia, division FROM equipos";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Exportar a csv</title>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<br /><br />  
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
    <h2 align="center">Exportar datos de BD a un CSV</h2>  
    <h3 align="center">Datos de Equipos</h3>                 
    <br />  
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                <th>Nombre</th>  
                <th>Ciudad</th>  
                <th width=5%>Conferencia</th>
                <th>Division</th>
                <th width=10%>Borrar dato</th>
            </tr>  
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>  
            <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row["ciudad"]; ?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $row["conferencia"]; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row["division"]; ?></td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href='delete.php?id=".$row['nombre']."'>Borrar</a></td>
                </td>
            </tr>  
            <?php } ?>  
        </table>  
    </div>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Y este seria el delete.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['nombre'];
$dbname = "nba";
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM equipos WHERE nombre = $id";

if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
    mysqli_close($connect);
    header('Location: basenba.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record";
}
?>
```

Siempre me salta el echo "Error deleting record"
Tambien hice un var_dump a $id en el archivo delete.php y me da NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate que en el link del formulario le estás pasando un parámetro llamado id (`delete.php?id=".$row['nombre']`) y en delete.php estás buscando un parámetro llamado nombre (`$id = $_GET['nombre']`). En delete.php haz esto, por ejemplo:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Por otro lado, en el formulario, a la hora de crear el link, no estás introduciendo correctamente el dato de la variable `$row`. Deberías hacerlo así:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>">Borrar</a>
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, me pasa en la variable " string(7) "".$row[" "

Comment: El link del formulario déjalo como estaba: <a class="btn btn-danger" href='delete.php?id=".$row['nombre']."'>Borrar</a>. Con modificar el archivo php con $id = $_GET['id']; ya debería funcionar.

Comment: El formulario no lo toque, solo cambie el id como me dijiste y pasa lo que te comente anteriormente

Comment: No veo bien el error en tu anterior comentario. ¿Puedes editar el mensaje, por favor?

Comment: Simplemente cambie lo que me recomendaste, el  `$id = $_GET['nombre']).`por  el `$id = $_GET['id'];` . Tengo un `var_dump($id);` para ver que valor me recoge del formulario. Antes del cambio me daba null y ahora me recoge `string(7) "".$row["` .Llegue a pensar que seria problema de las comillas pero yo no las veo mal..

Comment: Había un error en el formulario. He editado mi respuesta. Desgraciadamente, no puedo comprobarlo ahora mismo, pero se trata de escribir el valor de $row['nombre'] en el formulario tal como lo estabas haciendo con los otros campos.

Comment: Corregí el link y ahora me envia `string(7) ""76ers""` pero sigue sin borrar la fila

Comment: Ya encontre el fallo, proviene de la base de datos ya que desde el gestor tampoco puedo borrar. Gracias por la ayuda igualmente ya que el codigo estaba incorrecto tambien